# Android : Typeface is changed when i apply password Type on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, typeface

I use **FloatLabel** library (https://github.com/weddingparty/AndroidFloatLabel) to add a little animation when user begin to write something in an EditText Android.

My problem is that the typeface seems to be changed when i apply the password type to my EditText. I would like to keep the same typeface as normal. (see picture 1)

[image]

But when i add the following line to apply password type, the typeface of hint seems to be changed !

```
pass.getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

[image]

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The following might solve it for you.

```
pass.setTypeface(user.getTypeface());
```

Essentially it just passes the `Typeface` of your username field and passes it as the `Typeface` for your password field.

---

I found an explanation of this in the [Dialogs API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

> **Tip:** By default, when you set an EditText element to use the
>   `"textPassword"` input type, the font family is set to monospace, so you
>   should change its font family to `"sans-serif"` so that both text fields
>   use a matching font style.

In otherwords, a fix that can be done in XML would be as follows:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint="@string/password"/>
```

Comment: `fontFamily` is introduced in api level 16! what for 2.2?

Comment: This is exactly the solution. Without having to set thing in code with setTypeface() and setTransformationMethod(), which don't even work fully because the next letters that you type  are hidden and not shown

Comment: what is `user` ?

Answer (score 6):

For some reason I didn't have to set the transformation method so this may be a better solution.
In MyActivity:

```
  EditText editText_password = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    editText_password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me when using a custom font - set inputType back to text and then set the transformation

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is just to save the `typeface` before you change the `inputType` and reapply it after. Strangely this doesn't happen when set the `inputType` in `xml` but happens when setting programatically.

```
val typeface = editText.typeface
editText.inputType = inputType
editText.typeface = typeface
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use android:hit, and setHitColor in your activity, it will not affect the normal input

Answer (score 1):

**Set the inputType as "text" in the xml,**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

**Then make the EditText in the activity as**

```
mEdtConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
mEdtConfirmPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be late to answer this question but i have came across this problem. So thought to answer this. I have solved it by `Implementing a CustomTextWatcher`.

**Here is the snippet**

```
private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText mEditText;

    public CustomTextWatcher(EditText e) { 
        mEditText = e;
        mEditText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        mEditText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        mEditText.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
        if(s.length() <= 0){
            mEditText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        } else {
            mEditText.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
        }


    }
}
```

Here is how you can use it in your application

```
EditText pin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin);
pin.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(pin));
```