# How to style hint for EditText with inputType set to textPassword in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

Style of text for `hint` changes when I set `inputType=textPassword` in my EditText. Please see this image:

[image: screenshot of EditTexts]

Both EditTexts have same XML but the upper has `inputType` set to `textPassword`.

How do I make them look the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android : Typeface is changed when i apply password Type on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117178/android-typeface-is-changed-when-i-apply-password-type-on-edittext)

Comment: I've upvoted your question, this seems legit to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Edittext Typeface default programmatically

```
password.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: What about the font that is displayed while the keyboard is open? it's still showing as a monspaced font

Answer (score 2):

The problem is text  setTypeface.

> Tip: By default, when you set an EditText element to use the
>   "textPassword" input type, the font family is set to monospace, so you
>   should change its font family to "sans-serif" so that both text fields
>   use a matching font style.

For more details please refer this link,
[Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117178/android-typeface-is-changed-when-i-apply-password-type-on-edittext)

Answer (score 1):

In the EditText inputType set to textPassword the font will change 
use TextInputLayout for the EditText Password field

Try this code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_password"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_password"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/floating_text_color_accent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```